# Key cover replacemets

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

My Macbook Pro has just lost it's warrenty 1yr and 2months old and I've had to get the entire keyboard replaced, the hard disk replaced and now one of the new key caps has fallen off and can't be popped back like others have when they've fallen off...again.
Can I order a new cap cover in the store?
If so how much will it cost?
and before you ask I don't have an amazon account or any online shopping account for various reasons so would rather just buy the key cap in store if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Since online shopping is out of question the local Apple Store might help you with the parts,

the instructions you can find at [iFixit](http://www.ifixit.com/)

or [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JjRTQIfVTgU)

Comment: Thanks so much I was pretty worried it's literally just a case of popping the case cover on and that's it not technical repair needed. Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: correct :) and a piece of advice.. it is intended to be used as a computer not as a meet tenderizer (means be gentle with it)